# Resize height of a cell in a html table

Tags: html, css

Resize height of a cell in a table.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">Amount1</th>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">Amount2</th>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">Total</th>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The result is,

[image]

I want the size of the cell border to be reduced less than 10px, though height is provided as 5px, it is not reducing the sized. Any suggestion would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prevent a cell from expanding table height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10031643/prevent-a-cell-from-expanding-table-height)

Comment: Are you talking the cell border, or the cell padding?

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce height of the last row putting `style="line-height: 5px;"` at that level, like:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">Amount1</th>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">Amount2</th>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="line-height: 5px;">
      <th style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">Total</th>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">100</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Or if you want to reduce height of all rows, the same may be put at `table` level.

Answer (score 0):

The `<div>` element is used to wrap the content inside each `<th>` (table header) cell. The `height: 5px;` style applied to the `<div>` sets the height of the header cell to 5 pixels.

This approach provides a way to control the height of specific cells in the table while allowing for additional styling flexibility.

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">
        Amount1
      </div>
    </th>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">
        Amount2
      </div>
    </th>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <div style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4; height:5px">
        total
      </div>
    </th>
    <td style="border: 1px solid black; border-color: #96D4D4;">100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you create this answer with [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)?

Comment: No, Not create by ChatGPT

Comment: The language in your comments says otherwise tho...

Comment: Apologies for any confusion. I may have misunderstood the question. While I didn't directly use ChatGPT to create the content, I did seek assistance for text formation and clarity. I appreciate your understanding.